# invalidIdentifiers. Приложение не видит покупку в Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchases

Бьюсь с этим уже несколько дней, мое приложение не видит покупку, которую я добавил в iTunes Connect. Пробовал уже добавлять разные покупки, толку 0. Может есть какая-то тонкость, которую я упустил.

Я добавил not consumed покупку у себя в iTunes connect, пытаюсь получить ее из приложения но он ее не видит. Скриншот из itunes connect[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
func(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("IAP is eanabled, loading")
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "ru.treedeo.putTheBolts.removeAd")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers:  productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }

func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product )
    }

}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")

    let purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "ru.treedeo.putTheBolts.removeAd":
            print("remove ads")
        default:
            print("IAP not setup")
        }

    }
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased:
            print("buy, ok unlock iap here")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "ru.treedeo.putTheBolts.removeAd":
                print("remove ads")

                            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            print("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
{
    print("finish trans")
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
}
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
{
    print("remove trans");
}
```

В функции productsRequest сам request приходит с ошибкой: 
[image: пустой request]

In-app Purchase в свойствах проекта подключил. 
Надеюсь на вашу помощь и советы. Спасибо!

Comment: Я так понимаю, чтобы тестировать покупку не одобренную в аппстор, надо создавать специальные тестовые аккаунты и тестировать ими. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: Я так понял, этот аккаунт нужен для того, что бы совершать тестовые покупки, без списания средств с карты...

Comment: Я так понимаю, что покупка у вас не видна, поскольку она не одобрена. Либо загружайте версию в аппсотр и ждите, когда одбрят, либо пробуйте тестировать в сэндбоксе тестовыми аккаунтами.

Comment: Я создал тестовый аккаунт в sandbox и залоснился с его App ID в устройстве. Все равно никаких результатов. Связанно ли это с тем, что у меня не указаны банковские реквизиты в developer.apple?